# Cmd command. Delete a hidden file without extension by filename mask

Tags: windows, command-line, filenames

How can I delete a hidden file without extension in the specific directory by filename mask (QWER)?

`del /A:H "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\QWER@*."`

Comment: del doesn't have a /A switch you're thinking of DIR.   from memory i've managed to delete "hidden" files usually eg del thefileabc1.. You should give a command proving that the file is hidden e.g. DIR and it doesn't show it.. dir /ah and it does. And attrib to show the (at least basic) attributes of it.